# Office 365, SharePoint, Azure Active Directory write-back

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure-ad

Is there a way to update Azure Active Directory from within O365 Sharepoint?
I would like employees to have the ability to update basic information like phone number, etc.
Previously on-prem we could do this, but I am having difficulty finding information specific to O365 SharePoint and Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 1):

Have users use https://myaccount.microsoft.com for write-back. If you're synchronizing from Active Directory, then *no* as Azure AD will block most writable fields.

From SPO, there is no built-in mechanism to do this.